# grep just last ocurrence of multiple files

Tags: arrays, grep, find, ubuntu-16.04

Okay So i have around 600 folders, each folder has its logs, for see general logs i just do

```
grep -r -InH "Resources"
```

And i get

```
    es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:16:00:36:58 INFO  Builder - Resources: 490|128|212
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:52:01:53:23 INFO  Builder - Resources: 403|68|161
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:85:03:09:55 INFO  Builder - Resources: 484|138|206
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:107:04:25:37 INFO  Builder - Resources: 451|105|162
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:130:05:41:08 INFO  Builder - Resources: 931|524|456
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:167:06:57:49 INFO  Builder - Resources: 614|179|235
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:189:08:14:04 INFO  Builder - Resources: 566|130|168
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:223:09:30:21 INFO  Builder - Resources: 584|147|162
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:257:10:45:52 INFO  Builder - Resources: 559|122|104
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:292:12:02:12 INFO  Builder - Resources: 654|203|156
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:314:13:18:13 INFO  Builder - Resources: 548|114|117
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:337:14:34:23 INFO  Builder - Resources: 742|295|268
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:371:15:49:55 INFO  Builder - Resources: 563|179|174
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:407:17:06:45 INFO  Builder - Resources: 511|139|100
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:440:18:22:39 INFO  Builder - Resources: 605|233|160
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:461:19:38:50 INFO  Builder - Resources: 700|328|220
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log:16:11:14:52 INFO  Builder - Resources: 1229|1229|777
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log:41:12:30:58 INFO  Builder - Resources: 795|590|421
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log:83:13:47:02 INFO  Builder - Resources: 546|165|194
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log:119:15:03:44 INFO  Builder - Resources: 601|194|192
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:48:13:12:33 INFO  Builder - Resources: 510|510|410
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:71:14:28:37 INFO  Builder - Resources: 433|438|336
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:108:15:44:34 INFO  Builder - Resources: 439|384|304
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:133:17:00:44 INFO  Builder - Resources: 471|300|303
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:156:18:16:45 INFO  Builder - Resources: 335|121|195
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:192:19:33:28 INFO  Builder - Resources: 550|292|321
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:215:20:49:19 INFO  Builder - Resources: 381|59|156
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:236:22:04:54 INFO  Builder - Resources: 461|110|200
es52/es52-fantazyl/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:260:23:21:27 INFO  Builder - Resources: 410|69|168
es52/es52-derekok18/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:16:00:37:04 INFO  Builder - Resources: 490|128|213
es52/es52-derekok18/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:40:01:53:14 INFO  Builder - Resources: 402|68|162
es52/es52-derekok18/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:75:03:09:25 INFO  Builder - Resources: 484|138|207
es52/es52-derekok18/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-14:97:04:25:53 INFO  Builder - Resources: 452|106|163
es52/es52-derekok18/logs/dsx.log.2018-09-13:264:23:21:06 INFO  Builder - Resources: 409|68|169
```

I just want to get from each folder logs, newest  not all. Just the last occurrence, the one thats more recent.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any input for us to test against so this is obviously untested but it should be close if not exactly right:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log.*' -exec awk '/Resources/{s=$0; n=NR} END{if (n) print FILENAME, n, s}' {} \;
```